# Approval process only for certain elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, approval-process, content-approval

I have the following requirements regarding document management. I know that I can activate this "approval function" for a complete document library. But if an employee whose documents are to be approved inserts a document into the library, it must be approved by an employee who has the approval right. However, this should only be the case for certain documents. In addition, a particular approver should receive an e-mail notifying him of the pending approval.

How can I set this up, what possibilities are there for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple approval workflow on this document library via Library settings->Workflow settings->Add a workflow-> Select a workflow template: Approval-SharePoint 2010.

When the employee upload the document to library, he can trigger this workflow manually or set automatically start workflow when an new item is created in workflow settings. Then there is an email automatically sent to approvers.